# How to filter a store with multiple values at once?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, sencha-architect

I have a Store attached to a grid with number of records. I have a combo box with mulitiSelect option. So whenever i select multiple values in the Combo box. the grid must be filtered with all the criteria provided. I can get the values from the combo box as comma separated values but unable to send them to store's filter config.

Please Help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A bit cleaner:

```
var store = grid.getStore();
var selectedItems = csvList.split(","); //your list of comma separated values
store.clearFilter();
store.filterBy(function(record, id){
    return Ext.Array.indexOf(selectedItems, record.get("value")) !== -1;
}, this);
```

Comment: @Mike When store has more than 10000+ records, ExtJS get an error "[E] InternalError: too much recursion"