# Filter a store with array of values from one property with ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm trying to apply a constraint on combobox. It's half-working at the moment.
On the combobox, I have this listener:

```
[...]
        listeners: {
            'focus': function (combo, value) {
                var orgComboVal = Ext.getCmp('Org1')
                var getOrgValue = orgComboVal.getValue();
                if (typeof getOrgValue !== undefined) {
                    reseaulist.clearFilter(true);
                    for (var q = 0, l = getOrgValue.length; q < l; q++) {
                        reseaulist.filter([
                            {property:'code_organisme', value: getOrgValue[q]}
                        ]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

**Ext.getCmp('Org1')** defines another combobox.
When **orgComboVal.getValue()** is a single value, the filter is well applying.

 but when it's an array of value, eg **["5", "9"]**, it's not working and the combobox supposed to be filtered shows no value (so I guess a filter is still applied but in an incorrect way).

I guess it's because the reseaulist.filter is called multiple time.
How can I achieve this ?

I saw the  **filterBy** method but I don't know how to make it work.

Also, this post is interesting : [How to filter a store with multiple values at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17697133/how-to-filter-a-store-with-multiple-values-at-once) but same, can't make it work since

```
getOrgValue.split(',')
```

is showing an error

```
(Object Array has no method split)
```

Any tips ? I'm using ExtJS 4.2.

**EDIT**

Thanks to @rixo, I've made it.
Also, I had to change some of the code he provided me, because the value of the Org1 combobox was always an array, even if empty, so the store filter was never cleared.

Here it is :

```
            'focus': function (combo, value) {
                var orgComboVal = Ext.getCmp('Org1')
                var values = orgComboVal.getValue();
                console.log(values)
                if (values != null) {
                    reseaulist.clearFilter(false);
                    if (Ext.isArray(values)) {
                        if (0 < values.length) {
                            reseaulist.filterBy(function(record, id) {
                                return Ext.Array.contains(values, record.get('code_organisme'));
                            });
                        } else {
                        reseaulist.clearFilter(true);
                    }   
                    } 
                } 
            }
```

Comment: Please note that tags are not keywords.  Stuffing the tag list full of the same words that are in your question will not help categorize it.  Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each filter is applied one after the other on the previously filtered data set, so your code implements a logical AND. That's why all values are filtered out...

Here's an example using `filterBy` to accept any value that is in your array:

```
function (combo, value) {
    var orgComboVal = Ext.getCmp('Org1')
    var values = orgComboVal.getValue();
    if (values != null) {
        store.clearFilter(false);
        if (Ext.isArray(values)) {
            store.filterBy(function(record, id) {
                return Ext.Array.contains(values, record.get('code_organisme'));
            });
        } else {
            record.get('code_organisme') === values;
        }
    } else {
        store.clearFilter(true);
    }
}
```

Or you could also use a regex with the `filter` method:

```
function (combo, value) {
    var orgComboVal = Ext.getCmp('Org1')
    var values = orgComboVal.getValue();
    if (values != null) {
        var filterValue = Ext.isArray(values)
            ? new RegExp('^(?:' + Ext.Array.map(values, function(value){return Ext.escapeRe(value)}).join('|') + ')$')
            : values;
        store.clearFilter(false);
        store.filter('code_organisme', filterValue);
    } else {
        store.clearFilter(true);
    }
}
```

Concerning your error, arrays indeed don't have a `split` method. Strings can be split into an array. Arrays, on their side, can be *joined* into a string...

Comment: I tried your first solution and it's working, nice :) ! Just a point, the else {
        store.clearFilter(true);
    } is never triggered :(, so if the user erase the value from Org1 combo, the other combo is still filtered. I console.log the value of the Org1 combo, and when it's empty it returns [] and not null.

Comment: Ext.isArray(values) is always triggered because Org1 value is always an array, even if it's empty : []. So it always applies filter.

Comment: You can also use `Ext.isEmpty`, it will return true for empty arrays as well as undefined or null values.

Answer (score 0):

Try This....

> var getOrgValue = "5,9,4"; // array of value
>
> ```
> reseaulist.filterBy(function(rec, id) {
>   return getOrgValue.indexOf(rec.get('code_organisme')) !== -1;
> });
> ```