# Filter on a ExtJS store using an array

Tags: extjs, filter, extjs6

I have a remote store using a MySQL database.

> here is the store definition

```
Ext.define('rgpd.store.sOutil', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    requires: [
        'rgpd.model.mOutil'
    ],

    model: 'rgpd.model.mOutil',
    autoLoad: true,
    autoSync: true,
    pageSize: 0,
    remoteSort: true,
    remoteFilter: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        api: {
            create: 'data/app.php?class=Outil&action=create',
            read: 'data/app.php?class=Outil&action=read',
            update: 'data/app.php?class=Outil&action=update',
            destroy: 'data/app.php?class=Outil&action=destroy',
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data',
            totalProperty: 'totalCount',
            successProperty: 'success'
        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json',
            writeAllFields: false,
            successProperty: 'success',
            encode: true,
            extraParams: "id",
            idProperty: "id",
            rootProperty: 'data'
        }
    }
});
```

I have an array of ids, those i want to keep so i need to apply a filter.
I found 2 different solutions but none worked. The first was using [filtreBy method](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/modern/Ext.data.Store.html#method-filterBy)

```
Ext.getStore('sOutil').filterBy(function(record, id) {
    return Ext.Array.contains(ids_intervenant_outils, record.get('id'));
});
```

I did this bug i get an error in Firefox "too much recursion". So i tried an other way to do it and found this on an other stack-overflow post ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22144008/filter-a-store-with-array-of-values-from-one-property-with-extjs)) but I ge `Ext.escapeRe` which according to firefox "is not a function". I tried to find an other function i found `Ext.String.escapeRegex()` but I got one more error in Firefox "p.replace is not a function"

```
var filterValue = Ext.isArray(ids_intervenant_outils)
    ? new RegExp('^(?:' + Ext.Array.map(ids_intervenant_outils, function(value){return Ext.String.escapeRegex(value)}).join('|') + ')$')
    : values;
Ext.getStore('sOutil').clearFilter(false);
Ext.getStore('sOutil').filter('id', filterValue);
```

here is the too much recursion calls trace

```
RegExpGlobalReplaceOptFunc self-hosted:4702:22
[Symbol.replace] self-hosted:4499:24
replace self-hosted:5248:13
encodeString http://localhost/rgpd/extjs6/ext-all.js:22:383387
doEncode http://localhost/rgpd/extjs6/ext-all.js:22:382867
encodeObject http://localhost/rgpd/extjs6/ext-all.js:22:384535
doEncode http://localhost/rgpd/extjs6/ext-all.js:22:383117
encodeObject ...
```

Comment: Too much recursion is related to serialization when it's going through the writer. You have some self referential objects in the tree.

Answer (score 0):

found the issue for "too much recursion" error. `remoteFilter: true` must be `remoteFilter: false,` in the store definition.